# lua - how can i get char from stdin

Tags: lua

I know about io.stdin:read, but i want to have something equivalent to C "getchar".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read()` takes a parameter, one of which is the number of characters to read. If you call `read(1)` then you should get the behavior you are looking for.